# preview and print layout pagination are not same

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

when i preview a report it displays number of pages is 2 .

And when see that report in print layout it shows in single page.

Now i want both preview and print layout pagination are same.

Comment: It is normal that happens, because in normal view the render is done in HTML.

Comment: Hi Pook..any possibility to solve this issue..like page setup or report width and height properties.

Comment: Usually when this happens to me, are the margins of the page.

Comment: is it solve ,if i change the margin values?

Comment: when i change the page setup, it works. But i want to did that in a code level.without any manual setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a matrix in the report? If so there is a setting to consume white space, I've had issues with this in the past until I found this setting in the report properties.

Comment: shall i achieve this, without any manual setup i.e by using a code level process.

Comment: Yea it's in the properties of the matrix or report. So no code is needed.